# symfony: csDoctrineActAsSortablePlugin and i18n

Tags: symfony1, internationalization, jquery-ui-sortable

[originally posted on [Symfony forum](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=37340) but no (proper) answer has been given yet].

Has anyone ever managed to put Sortable behavior using csDoctrineActAsSortablePlugin on any model having i18n fields? 
Everything is installed fine but when trying to doctrine:data-load a fixtures file for the i18n model, it crashes by a MySQL integrity constraint violation about duplicate key entry. 
Is special handling required for i18n models?

My plugin version is 1.5.4.1 installed on symfony 1.4.8.

Apart from this, do you know of any other solutions (plugins) for adding "moveup" "movedown" functionality in the admin generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better workaround that the one originally posted on symfony forum.

1. In your `schema.yml` comment the `Sortable` behavior to all of your models and place an equivalent `position` column instead of this (this is the actual column that will be created by the plugin in the database for the specified model) with the following properties:

   ```
   position: { type: integer, notnull: false }
   ```
2. Run `symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load --no-confirmation`. This will correctly insert all the data in the database.
3. Restore your `schema.yml` and run `symfony doctrine:build --all-classes --model --forms --filters`. This will restore the `Sortable` behavior in your models without affecting your data.

Answer (score 3):

I've built a custom version of the sfDoctrineBuildTask class that curates this problem:

http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=37340#p136449

Comment: That's great! I'll give it a try and let you know. Have you thought of creating an extension plugin on top of csDoctrineActAsSortablePlugin? or submit a patch for the existing one?

Comment: The shortcoming with this approach is the need of keeping your data in `php` format. Although handy and more readable this format isn't compatible with the exportation of data (via `data-dump`) which always is in `YAML` format